# NSVisualEffectView on top of NSVisualEffectView

Tags: swift, cocoa, rounded-corners, nsvisualeffectview

When placing a NSVisualEffectView with blending mode behind window, behind another NSVisualEffectView with blending mode within window, and rounding the corners of the NSVisualEffectView that is on top, the corners that are on top of the NSVisualEffectView don't round correctly. The picture attached displays the issue.

I spent multiple hours trying to figure out why exactly this is happening but was unable to solve this issue. To round the corners of the NSVisualEffectView on top, I use the following code:

```
topVisualEffectView.wantsLayer = true
topVisualEffectView.masksToBounds = true
topVisualEffectView.cornerRadius = 30
```

[image]

Comment: I found a workaround that may be useful to some people. I originally wanted to use the NSVisualEffectView on top to blur an image view. Instead of doing this, I blur the image that the image view is displaying, and round the corners of the image view. This has the same effect, but does not glitch the corners.